# Scala Actor: Will messages passed from one actor to another within the same process always be processed in the original order?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka

Scala Actor : Will messages passed from one actor to another within the same process always be processed in the original order as sent ?

Answer (score 2):

Yep. For two actors this condition does hold.

> the messages are guaranteed to be ordered for a given pair of sender
>   and receiver actors. If an actor A sends messages X and Y in that
>   order, the actor B will receive no messages, only the message X, only
>   the message Y, or the message X, followed by the message Y.

Learning concurrent programming in scala, page 270

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. Just to mention that the paragraph cited by nikiforo in his answer has a different page number in the 2014 edition book, it is in page 380.

Answer (score 0):

Akka guarantees that messages will be received in the same order that they were sent **assuming they are delivered at all**, but does not guarantee message delivery. The akka documentation is quite clear on this as follows:

> "for a given pair of actors, messages sent directly from the first to the second will not be received out-of-order"

Also, while messages sent via an intermediate actor are normally not guaranteed to be delivered in the same order to the final destination actor, this limitation is "eliminated under certain conditions" when running in the context of a single JVM. As you are asking specifically about in-process messaging this may be relevant to you although the documentation advises not to rely on this behaviour.

There are examples and further clarification in the Akka documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#The_Rules_for_In-JVM__Local__Message_Sends